# Create a build failure report in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm looking for a way in Teamcity to produce an email report that will be sent on a weekly basis to a number of users that will list all the projects and configurations in Teamcity and show how many failed builds have occurred in the last week for each configuration.

Is this even possible in Teamcity? Or is there a plugin or build monitor that I can use for this? I'm using Teamcity 8.06.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such built-in functionality in TeamCity, neither I know some plugins which do that. So the only option is to write new plugin or some script which will use rest api to generate weekly report.